# Why does the content of a pointer change?

Tags: c++

I'm a C# programmer and now using C++ to do some work.

```
pair<Point,double>* p=NULL;
Sphere* sphere=NULL;

for (int i=0;i<spheres.size();i++)
{
    vector<pair<Point,double>> solution=findIntersection(Point(ray.origin),Point(ray.direction.x,ray.direction.y,ray.direction.z),spheres[i]);

    if(solution.size()==0)
        continue;


    if(p==NULL || solution[0].second<p->second)
    {
        p=&solution[0];
        sphere=&spheres[i];
    }
}


if(p==NULL)
    return backgroundColor;
else
{
    Color c=localIlluminate(p->first,*sphere);
    return c;
}
```

I want `p.first` to have the smallest value, and `sphere` be the cooresponding sphere that is used to get `p`.

After debugging, I find the code doesn't work. In the first loop, `p` will be assigned the address of `solution[0]`, assuming the value is {(0,0),0}. Then the loop continues and when `i=1`, assume solution[0] becomes {(1,2),3} and value of p also becomes {(1,2),3}.

I don't expect the value of `p` to change. How should I fix it?

Comment: You are saving a pointer to an element that is going to disappear at the next iteration (since the local vector is going to be replaced, and you are pointing inside it); save a copy instead of a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing the reference to a local variable outside the scope in which the local variable is declared.

Every iteration `solution` is not valid anymore, then the address to it shouldn't be considered valid. To obtain what you need you should assign the variable by value, so that you actually copy the contained value, eg:

```
pair<Point, double> p = std::make_pair(whatever, std::numeric_limits<double>::max());

for (...)
{
   if (solution[0].second < p.second)
     p = solution[0];
}
```

The fact that the address changes can be caused by multiple reasons, but you shouldn't bother understanding why, just avoid this kind of situation. Your misconception comes from the fact that C# has a garbage collection which prevents `solution[0]` from becoming invalid, which is not true for C++, when variable are declared on stack.

Comment: In C#, an object type can either be null or a concrete value. If the value is null, it means solution is not found. In C++, do I have to use one more variable to determine if a solution was found, or use a dummy value as you suggests and check the dummy value outside the loop?

Comment: @LoveRight You can use boost::optional if you need a nullable type, but in this case the solution provided by Jack is better.

Comment: @LoveRight: actually it's different, in C# an object can be `null` or a pointer to an object allocated on heap. In C++ you have two ways to instantiate an object (actually more), you can allocate them on heap or allocate them on stack, the first kind is quite similar to C# but the latter is more related to how the hardware stack is implemented. Stack objects are more efficient and should be used when possible.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign to p it points to the adresss of &solution[0] but on the next iteration of the loop that variable goes poof and a new one gets created and p points to either random stuff or something else.

It might be better to just store a copy in p, so make p a regular variable and copy over the solution[0] by assigning. You can have another bool variable to determine if a solution was found.

```
pair<Point,double> p;
Sphere sphere;
bool solutionFound = false;

for (int i=0;i<spheres.size();i++)
{
    vector<pair<Point,double>> solution=findIntersection(Point(ray.origin),Point(ray.direction.x,ray.direction.y,ray.direction.z),spheres[i]);

    if(solution.size()==0)
        continue;


    if(!solutionFound || solution[0].second < p.second)
    {
        p=solution[0];
        sphere=spheres[i];
        solutionFound = true;
    }
}


if(!solutionFound)
    return backgroundColor;
else
{
    Color c=localIlluminate(p.first, sphere);
    return c;
}
```